# how to remove focus on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove focus on button click .Actually in my css it is written this

```
button:focus,
a:focus {
  outline-offset: 2px;
  outline-width: 2px !important;
  outline-style: dotted !important;
  outline-color: currentColor;
}
```

when I click on button it focus my button here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-snow-x8fih?file=/src/App.js

I have already tried `blur` event

```
function handleProductNavigation(event) {
    btnRef.current.blur();
    console.log(btnRef.current.blur);
    //event.currentTarget.blur();
    //props.onChange(event, '0E3B648885C24A02B5B2676BEB82C7E9', '', 'rc20p2-open');
  }
```

after click it look like this

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting the behaviour you describe on Windows using Google Chrome. After I release the click, the dotted line disappears.

Comment: why it show dotted line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `blur` works as intended and the outline goes away after the click. But if you don't want to show it at all when clicking and only show it for tab-focus there is a `:focus-visible` pseudo-class which is basically keyboard-only-focus and it has reasonable browser support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible